# OpenCV Camera Calibration tutorial crashes

Tags: c++, opencv

By following [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html):

I created an XML configuration file, and a list of asymmetric circle grid images to run the camera calibration C++ sample. Everything is checked in [here](https://github.com/01binary/calibration).

When I set board width to 5 and height to 4 I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.0-dev) /home/zero/opencv-master/modules/core/src/convert_c.cpp:112: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels() in function 'cvConvertScale'
```

All the images are exactly the same, taken using Raspberri Pi camera in a sequence.

When I set board width to 4 and height to 3, I get this instead:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.0-dev) /home/zero/opencv-master/modules/calib3d/src/circlesgrid.cpp:1524: error: (-215:Assertion failed) h >= 2 && w >= 2 in function 'getCornerSegments'
```

Has anyone gotten this sample to work, or is it hopelessly broken? Someone created the same issue in OpenCV but it was never resolved:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6503

Comment: What is your real board size ? Any scenario you experienced code working ? Board width and height are the square(circle) numbers of your real board ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I tried width and height by counting circle rows and columns, and the second example is counting spaces between circles. Both result in cryptic crashes. Here's one of the images: https://github.com/01binary/calibration/blob/master/images/x1.jpg?raw=true

Comment: I think it can be better sharing your code, even you are saying you followed that tutorial. There can be something you didnt notice

Comment: I didn't write any code, just ran their executable that they built from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.cpp

Comment: `cv::imread()` fails "silently" if it cannot read the image -- e.g. if path is invalid, it just returns an empty `cv::Mat` -- and I am wondering it's failing to read images here. One way to check would be add an assertion on `result.width > 0 && result.height > 0` here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.cpp#L169L170

Comment: Thank you I will try it. Currently attempting to setup remote debugging

Answer (score 0):

The issue I linked in the original post was actually resolved some time later and contains the solution:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6503

> Run is OK if set config size_width and size_height with n - 1 and m - 1(n is number of columns in real board-size, m is number of rows in real board-size)

The issue was that width and height were not counted the way I assumed (unfortunately it was not clear from documentation how they were counted).

Apologies to everyone who commented!